# How do I solve this python error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, authentication, auth0

The code is below and every time I try to run this code I get the same error. How do I solve this?

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("")

headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" }

conn.request("GET", "/violetwears.auth0.com/api/v2/users/USER_ID", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Wrong host, firewall/network connection issue, or no running server (http vs https?) on the target machine. *A TCP connection was not / could not be established to the server*, and thus there was no authentication attempt. If if was an HTTP/bearer authentication issue after a connection had been made, there would have been *a* HTTP response message with code - eg. a 403.

Comment: Did you replace your access token and user_id? I have to ask... :)

Comment: Yes, I replaced the access token and id

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this issue for a while now but it finally worked when I passed the domain to the HTTPSConnection constructor and remove it from the request url as follows. Credit to the [answer here on auth0 community](https://community.auth0.com/t/troubles-while-setting-up-auth0-extension-api-python/21731)

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("violetwears.auth0.com")

headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" }

conn.request("GET", "/api/v2/users/USER_ID", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```